# I need help finding the right strategy

Tags: laravel, design-patterns

Following figure is a part of my private project.

[image: This is my entity model]

Next is my classes..

[image: This is my class diagram..]

What I'm trying to make is a list of several objects as elements. This list can have other lists as elements, and the objects that can be thought of as leaf nodes are Mpml objects.

```
// example
[
    1 => Mpml object, // Mpml is leaf object.
    2 => Exam object, // The second object have some other childrens.
    3 => Mpml object
]
```

The second diagram is the result of thinking about how to implement it. But no matter how much I think, it feels still something wrong. HELP!!

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and have a very basic knowledge of design pattern(like, knowing what it is but cannot easily implement it).

Comment: is this a database relationship?

Comment: First diagram is database relationship, yes. Second one is class diagram.

Comment: what are you databases? and what relation do you want them to have

Comment: ah.. MySQL. table storage engines are all same as MyISAM

Comment: no... I'm referring to the tables. So what are your tables and what relationship do they have

Comment: oh get it. a.. there is 1:1 Polymorphic relationship between `Exam`, `Type`, ... , `Book` (Collectors) and `MpmlCollection`.

Comment: and 1:Many relationship between `MpmlCollection` and `Item`

Comment: and 1:1 Polymorphic relationship between `Item` and `Exam, Type, ..., Book, Mpml` table.

Comment: so what is the question you want to be solve?

Comment: I think there is something structural design problem in my solution. So I need advice because I can't find a better way for myself.

Comment: I feel like I'm messing up to do things outside my ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to see [this](https://carlillo.hashnode.dev/understanding-design-patterns-facade-using-pokemon-and-dragonball-examples-cjz8ikt0c001cjss1a3lfv7zd) article.

You need to first build your sample app to know what are missing in your pattern.

Then you can now think on how can you add the methods or strategy you want to do.

Sometimes things are get clearer when you actually using them.

Then do a test research on your app. Ask the tester on what they want your app to be.

Here one strategy on your **DATABASE RELATIONSHIP** [Polymorphic Relationship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7T1689IvPQ&t=686s)

Comment: I don't think my question was clear. Thanks for helping me to the end. I'm gonna take a closer look at what you told me and try again. Thank you!!

Comment: no problem you only need to specify the question you want to solve in the last part. I'm also learning **English**